# Find row number in excel using selenium Python

Tags: python, excel, selenium

What is the syntax to find out the row number of a particular value in excel using Selenium Python?

```
import openpyxl

Workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:example.xlsx")  # path of the workbook will be provided this way
Worksheet = Workbook["Driver"]
for i in range(2, Worksheet.max_row+1):
    Workcell = Worksheet.cell(row=i, column=2)
    val = Workcell.value
    if val == "Y":`enter code here`
```

How to find out row number for the value "Y"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe with

```
import openpyxl

Workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:example.xlsx")  # path of the workbook will be provided this way
Worksheet = Workbook["Driver"]
for row_num, i in enumerate(range(2, Worksheet.max_row+1)):
    Workcell = Worksheet.cell(row=i, column=2)
    val = Workcell.value
    row_num +=2 # because excel firsts row is 2 and enumerate first is 0 
    if val == "Y":`enter code here
```

Comment: @SowjanyaHM, don't forget to accept the answer if it has helped =)